# Notifications that open by themselves

Tags: java, android, notifications

the notifications of my app open without a logical sense than the code that I wrote. I should receive a notification every day at the same time but if I open the app I get the same notification. This is the code in MainActivity:

```
public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
         intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar.getTimeInMillis(),24*60*60*1000,pendingIntent);
}
```

And this is MyAlarmService:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver {

 NotificationManager nm;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  nm = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  CharSequence from = "Locali Torino";
  CharSequence message = "Visita le serate!";
  Intent action = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    action, 0);



  Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.disco,
    "Visita le serate!", System.currentTimeMillis());
  notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
  notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  nm.notify(0, notif);  

 }
}
```

Why I get notifications when I open the app or at least not only at the set time?

EDIT

MyAlarmService:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver {

 NotificationManager nm;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


  nm = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  CharSequence from = "Locali Torino";
  CharSequence message = "Visita le serate!";
  Intent action = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    action, 0);



  Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.disco,
    "Visita le serate!", System.currentTimeMillis());
  notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
  notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  nm.notify(0, notif);  
  SharedPreferences mPref = context.getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPref.edit();



    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mEditor.putLong("UPDATE_TIME", time);
    mEditor.commit();
 }And this is MainActivity:

public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class);


         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
         intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

         long startAt;
         long period;

         SharedPreferences mPref = context.getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

         long dif = System.currentTimeMillis() - mPref.getLong("UPDATE_TIME", 0);

         if (dif >= UPDATE_PERIOD) {
           startAt = 0;
           period = UPDATE_PERIOD;
         } else {
           startAt = dif;
           period = dif;
         }


         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startAt, period,pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The service runs when you register it, so what you need to do is pass a boolean value with the intent when registering the service to prevent it from running when the application runs, but to run periodically thereafter.

In your activity add:

```
intent.putExtra("run", false);
```

Then in MyAlarmService:

```
private boolean run = true;
// ...
action.getBooleanExtra("run", run);
if(run) {
    // notifications code
} else {
    run = true;
}
```

Comment: In this way? `Intent action = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);` or `Intent action = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works exactly as code is written. The cause of that behavior is your `startAt` parameter in `setRepeating` method.

```
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                 calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                 24*60*60*1000,
                 pendingIntent);
```

`calendar.getTimeInMillis()` time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).

For example :

```
//send first alarm after 1 second and repeat it every 24 hours
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                 1000,
                 24*60*60*1000,
                 pendingIntent);

//send first alarm after 10 second and repeat it every 24 hours
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                 10000,
                 24*60*60*1000,
                 pendingIntent);
```

**UPDATE :**

You need to save your last update time :

```
public class MyAlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver {

 NotificationManager nm;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  //send alarm here
  //...

    SharedPreferences mPref = context.getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPref.edit();
    mEditor.putLong("UPDATE_TIME", time);
    mEditor.commit();
 }
}
```

Then you can make your `setRepeatingAlarm` method like this :

```
public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
         intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

         long startAt;
         long period;

         SharedPreferences mPref = context.getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

         long dif = System.currentTimeMillis() - mPref.getLong("UPDATE_TIME", 0);

         if (dif >= UPDATE_PERIOD) {
           startAt = 0;
           period = UPDATE_PERIOD;
         } else {
           startAt = dif;
           period = dif;
         }

         am.setRepeating(
               AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
               startAt,
               period,
               pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: and how should I do? if I put the time every time you launch the app I see the notification

Comment: I did not understand where you have defined `update_period` and `time`

Comment: You should save current time in receiver

Comment: long time = System.curTimeMillis()

Comment: in this way is always the same defect as soon as I open the app notification appears

Comment: I do not understand why