# Use notifications and alarm

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I use notifications and alarm in my android app but I do not understand why even if I set the alarm, I see a notification every time I launch the app.
This is MainActivity:

```
public void setRepeatingAlarm() {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class);


         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
         intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

         long startAt;
         long period;

         SharedPreferences mPref = context.getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

         long dif = System.currentTimeMillis() - mPref.getLong("UPDATE_TIME", 0);

         if (dif >= UPDATE_PERIOD) {
           startAt = 0;
           period = UPDATE_PERIOD;
         } else {
           startAt = dif;
           period = dif;
         }


         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startAt, period,pendingIntent);
}
```

This is MyAlarmService:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver {

 NotificationManager nm;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


  nm = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  CharSequence from = "Locali Torino";
  CharSequence message = "Visita le serate!";
  Intent action = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    action, 0);



  Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.disco,
    "Visita le serate!", System.currentTimeMillis());
  notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
  notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  nm.notify(0, notif);  
  SharedPreferences mPref = context.getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPref.edit();



    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mEditor.putLong("UPDATE_TIME", time);
    mEditor.commit();
 }
}
```

I would like to see a notification every day at the same time and not every time I open the app. Thank you.

EDIT

This is OnCreate:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   StrictMode.enableDefaults(); //STRICT MODE ENABLED

   context=MainActivity.this;


   am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   setRepeatingAlarm();





   locale = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locale7);
   lunedi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lunedi7);
   martedi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.martedi7);
   mercoledi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mercoledi7);
   giovedi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.giovedi7);
   venerdi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.venerdi7);
   sabato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sabato7);
   domenica = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.domenica7);

   Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chunkfive.otf");
   locale.setTypeface(font);
   lunedi.setTypeface(font);
   martedi.setTypeface(font);
   mercoledi.setTypeface(font);
   giovedi.setTypeface(font);
   venerdi.setTypeface(font);
   sabato.setTypeface(font);
   domenica.setTypeface(font);

    getData();



}
```

Comment: post ur oncreate of activity

Comment: where is UPDATE_PERIOD defined and what is its default value

Comment: `private static final long UPDATE_PERIOD = 0;`

Comment: so everytime Activity is called UPDATE_PERIOD will be zero

Comment: and then?  I do not understand

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notifications that open by themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591166/notifications-that-open-by-themselves)

Answer (score 0):

First thing everytime  Activity is called UPDATE_PERIOD will be zero .So startUp is always zero.

second - everytime you launch an application you are calling setRepeatingAlarm() from oncreate of Activity. So your alarm is getting rest evertime.

Third -Add current time to setrepeating() otherwise alarm will be called  the moment it is set.

So make other change(as per your your requirement) and this one too.

```
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+startAt, period,pendingIntent);
```

Update :

Store UPDATE_PERIOD period in sharedpreference and retrieve it before doing any thing in oncreate

Comment: how should I do to make sure that does not see a notification every time I open the app?

Comment: send me ur complete project